# Simulation background-size: cover in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm drawing images on a canvas like this:

```js
ctx.drawImage(data[i].image, data[i].pos.x, data[i].pos.y, data[i].pos.w, data[i].pos.h);
```

The picture is getting stretched and I don't want this. How can I simulate the CSS property?

```css
background-size: cover
```

when drawing images on the canvas?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

see the difference between `100% 100%` (what I currently have) and `cover` (my goal).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated to get a cover functionality, though here is one solution for this:

**Updated 2016-04-03** to address special cases. Also see @Yousef's comment below.

```
/**
 * By Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen
 *
 * drawImageProp(context, image [, x, y, width, height [,offsetX, offsetY]])
 *
 * If image and context are only arguments rectangle will equal canvas
*/
function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        x = y = 0;
        w = ctx.canvas.width;
        h = ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    // default offset is center
    offsetX = typeof offsetX === "number" ? offsetX : 0.5;
    offsetY = typeof offsetY === "number" ? offsetY : 0.5;

    // keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
    if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
    if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
    if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;

    var iw = img.width,
        ih = img.height,
        r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
        nw = iw * r,   // new prop. width
        nh = ih * r,   // new prop. height
        cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    // decide which gap to fill    
    if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;                             
    if (Math.abs(ar - 1) < 1e-14 && nh < h) ar = h / nh;  // updated
    nw *= ar;
    nh *= ar;

    // calc source rectangle
    cw = iw / (nw / w);
    ch = ih / (nh / h);

    cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
    cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

    // make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
    if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
    if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
    if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

    // fill image in dest. rectangle
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch,  x, y, w, h);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
drawImageProp(ctx, image, 0, 0, width, height);
```

and it will scale the image proportionally to fit inside in that container.

Use the two last parameters to offset the image:

```
var offsetX = 0.5;   // center x
var offsetY = 0.5;   // center y
drawImageProp(ctx, image, 0, 0, width, height, offsetX, offsetY);
```

Comment: I found this to be a good starting point, but there are a number of bugs relating to floating point precision to be aware of. For example, suppose a dimension is 728 and a ratio is 0.25686813186813184; the result is 186.99999999999997, and the actual canvas width is 187, so the check if the height/width is lesser than the width/height will be true, thus the aspect ratio changing when it should not. I found the best approach was to wrap my decimal numbers with parseInt and toFixed, like so: parseInt(num.toFixed(8)).

Comment: You should test offsets for var type because `0` will return `false`, which will then set offset back to its default. Something like `offsetX = typeof offsetX === 'number' ? offsetX : 0.5;`

Comment: @rayfranco thanks! you are absolute right - I overlooked this one. Answer updated.

Comment: @K3N This is awesome. One question - how could I alter this to accept an argument which would allow the image to be scaled/zoomed (i.e. using value form `input[type=range]` ) while keeping a central origin ( i.e. `background-position: center`)

Comment: Great answer! I noticed there can be some issues with floating points in JS. For example, img.width=225, img.height=400, w=58, h=58. In Chrome it will resize to the wrong dimension.

I've solved this by changing:
`if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;
    if (nh < h) ar = h / nh;`
into
`if (Math.round(nw) < w) ar = w / nw;
if (Math.round(nh) < h) ar = h / nh;`
but not sure whether that's the cleanest solution

Comment: @Yousef thanks, and you are right. I actually discovered the same just recently - in some special cases the result becomes wacky. I came up with a similar approach but checking for equal value using an epsilon error margin. It seemed to work in my tests and I will test yours as well which seem to be doing about the same.

Comment: In some case, if you're using an image already rendered in the DOM, it is possible that the canvas's result not extacly emulates a background-cover. To solve this issue, use `img.naturalWidth` and `img.winHeight` instead of `img.width`and `img.height`. You'll be sure that value are based on original image width and height. (just not compatible for IE8 and lower)

Comment: Looks like Demo page is no longer available

Comment: Demo page is not available but anyway your code helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

If you're looking for a simpler solution that will work for most cases, and also includes css `contain`-like functionality, try this:

```
function fit(contains) {
  return (parentWidth, parentHeight, childWidth, childHeight, scale = 1, offsetX = 0.5, offsetY = 0.5) => {
    const childRatio = childWidth / childHeight
    const parentRatio = parentWidth / parentHeight
    let width = parentWidth * scale
    let height = parentHeight * scale

    if (contains ? (childRatio > parentRatio) : (childRatio < parentRatio)) {
      height = width / childRatio
    } else {
      width = height * childRatio
    }

    return {
      width,
      height,
      offsetX: (parentWidth - width) * offsetX,
      offsetY: (parentHeight - height) * offsetY
    }
  }
}

export const contain = fit(true)
export const cover = fit(false)
```

*slightly modified version of [intrinsic-scale](https://github.com/bfred-it/intrinsic-scale) to include scale and offset*

Usage:

```
import {cover, contain} from './intrinsic-scale'

const {
  offsetX, 
  offsetY, 
  width, 
  height
} = cover(parentWidth, parentHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight)

// or...

const {
  offsetX, 
  offsetY, 
  width, 
  height
} = contain(parentWidth, parentHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight)

ctx.drawImage(image, offsetX, offsetY, width, height)
```

Answer (score 9):

Canvas image fitting canvas like background-size cover and contain

```
const coverImg = (img, type) => {
  const imgRatio = img.height / img.width
  const winRatio = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth
  if ((imgRatio < winRatio && type === 'contain') || (imgRatio > winRatio && type === 'cover')) {
    const h = window.innerWidth * imgRatio
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, (window.innerHeight - h) / 2, window.innerWidth, h)
  }
  if ((imgRatio > winRatio && type === 'contain') || (imgRatio < winRatio && type === 'cover')) {
    const w = window.innerWidth * winRatio / imgRatio
    ctx.drawImage(img, (win.w - w) / 2, 0, w, window.innerHeight)
  }
}
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/supah/pen/BaNBmmw)

Usage:

```
coverImg(myImage, 'cover');
coverImg(myImage, 'contain');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (based on @daviestar's answer):

```
getCanvas = function(img, w, h) {
   // Create canvas
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Set width and height
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    // Draw the image
    let containerRatio = h / w;
    let width = img.naturalWidth;
    let height = img.naturalHeight;
    let imgRatio = height / width;

    if (imgRatio > containerRatio) { // image's height too big
      height = width * containerRatio;
    } else { // image's width too big
      width = height / containerRatio;
    }

    let s = {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      offsetX: (img.naturalWidth - width) * .5,
      offsetY: (img.naturalHeight - height) * .5
    };
    ctx.drawImage(img, s.offsetX, s.offsetY, s.width, s.height, 0, 0, w, h);
    return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script is a reference from [@user1693593](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961894/9935654), and I do some modifications as below

- use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make the options more flexible
- The script provides a runnable example, so you don't worry the link is not found.

```html
<script>
  function clamp(num, a, b) {
    return num > b ? b
      : num < a ? a
        : num
  }

  /**
   * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx
   * @param {HTMLImageElement} img
   * @param {Number} dx
   * @param {Number} dy
   * @param {Number} dw
   * @param {Number} dh
   * @param {Number} offsetX
   * @param {Number} offsetY
   * */
  function drawImageProp(ctx, img, {dx = 0, dy = 0, dw = undefined, dh = undefined, offsetX = 0.5, offsetY = 0.5}) {

    dw = dw ?? ctx.canvas.width
    dh = dh ?? ctx.canvas.height

    // keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    offsetX = clamp(offsetX, 0, 1)
    offsetY = clamp(offsetY, 0, 1)

    let iw = img.width,
      ih = img.height,
      ratio = Math.min(dw / iw, dh / ih),
      nw = iw * ratio,
      nh = ih * ratio, // new prop. height
      sx, sy, sw, sh, ar = 1;

    // decide which gap to fill
    if (nw < dw) ar = dw / nw
    if (Math.abs(ar - 1) < 1e-14 && nh < dh) ar = dh / nh // updated
    nw *= ar
    nh *= ar

    // source rectangle
    sw = iw / (nw / dw)
    sh = ih / (nh / dh)

    sx = (iw - sw) * offsetX
    sy = (ih - sh) * offsetY

    // make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (sx < 0) sx = 0
    if (sy < 0) sy = 0
    if (sw > iw) sw = iw
    if (sh > ih) sh = ih

    img.onload = (event) => {
      // fill image in dest. rectangle
      ctx.drawImage(event.target, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
    }
  }

  // Test Only 
  window.onload = () => {
    const testArray = [
      ["Default", (ctx, img)=>{drawImageProp(ctx, img, {})}],
      ["Full", (ctx, img)=>{drawImageProp(ctx, img, {offsetY:0})}], // If you don't want to it cutting from two sides, you can set "offsetY = 0" then it will cut a large part from the bottom
      ["1/2",(ctx, img)=>{drawImageProp(ctx, img, {dx:window.innerWidth/4, dy:window.innerHeight/4, dw: window.innerWidth/2, dh:window.innerHeight/2})}],
        ["3/4",(ctx, img)=>{drawImageProp(ctx, img, {dx:window.innerWidth/8, dy:window.innerHeight/8, dw: window.innerWidth*3/4, dh:window.innerHeight*3/4})}]
    ]
    for (const [testName, drawFunc] of testArray) {
      const btn = document.createElement("button")
      btn.innerText = testName
      btn.onclick = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll(`canvas`).forEach(e=>e.remove()) // remove old data
        const img = new Image(590, 470)
        img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg"
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        drawFunc(ctx, img)
        document.querySelector(`body`).append(canvas)
      }
      document.querySelector(`body`).append(btn)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may concern, I was looking for this answer but had to develop my own solution written in typescript, with file type solution:

```
const resizeBase64Img = (
  base64: string, // image base64
  type: string, // image mime type
  newWidth: number, // new image width
  newHeight: number // new image height
) =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    // rejects promise if no document variable
    if (!document) {
      reject('document is not available');
    }
    // create a brand new canvas element
    const canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    // set its width
    canvasElement.width = newWidth;
    // and height
    canvasElement.height = newHeight;
    // adjust style for width
    canvasElement.style.width = newWidth.toString() + 'px';
    // and height
    canvasElement.style.height = newHeight.toString() + 'px';
    // get canvas context
    const context = canvasElement.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    // create nem image
    const img = new Image();
    // set it's source from base64 argument
    img.src = base64;
    // when it loads
    img.onload = () => {
      // get the imgRatioType: landscape or portrait
      const imgRatioType =
        img.width / img.height >= 1 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'; // 1 > landscape ; 1 < portrait

      // if image is a portrait, then what's limiting it's sWidth is the img width. Otherwise it'll be the img height
      const sWidth = imgRatioType === 'portrait' ? img.width : img.height;
      // if image is a landscape, then what's limiting it's sHeight is the img height. Otherwise it'll be the img width
      const sHeight = imgRatioType === 'landscape' ? img.height : img.width;
      // if landscape, the image width is equals to 2 equal sx plus the sWidth. Otherwise, it should be 0.
      const sx = imgRatioType === 'landscape' ? (img.width - sWidth) / 2 : 0;
      // if portrait, the image height is equals to 2 equal sy plus the sHeight. Otherwise, it should be 0.
      const sy = imgRatioType === 'portrait' ? (img.height - sHeight) / 2 : 0;

      // destination canvas should have no space on dx
      const dx = 0;
      // neither on dy
      const dy = 0;
      // it's dWidth should be equal to the canvas width
      const dWidth = canvasElement.width;
      // and the same applies to dHeight with height
      const dHeight = canvasElement.height;
      // use clearRect for setting pixels in a clear rectangle with defined width and height
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      // then draws the image
      context.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);

      // resolve the promise with canvas toDataUrl method using type argument for mime
      resolve(canvasElement.toDataURL(type));
    };
    img.onerror = (err) => {
      // if image fails to load, rejects promise
      reject(err);
    };
  });
```