# HTML5 - Canvas, drawImage() draws image blurry

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw the following image to a canvas but it appears blurry despite defining the size of the canvas. As you can see below, the image is crisp and clear whereas on the canvas, it is blurry and pixelated.

[image]

and here is how it looks (the left one being the original and the right one being the drawn-on canvas and blurry.)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```js
console.log('Hello world')

var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var playerImg = new Image()

// http://i.imgur.com/ruZv0dl.png sees a CLEAR, CRISP image
playerImg.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/ruZv0dl.png'
playerImg.width = 32
playerImg.height = 32

playerImg.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(playerImg, 0, 0, 32, 32);
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #ABABAB;
  position: relative;
  height: 352px;
  width: 512px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="352" width="521"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of Anti Aliasing.
Simply set the `imageSmoothingEnabled` to false like so

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Here is a jsFiddle verson

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mt8sk9cb/

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var playerImg = new Image()

// http://i.imgur.com/ruZv0dl.png sees a CLEAR, CRISP image
playerImg.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/ruZv0dl.png'

playerImg.onload = function() {
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(playerImg, 0, 0, 256, 256);
};
```

Comment: You should add the vendor prefixes, since this isn't a stabilized property.

Comment: @Canvas Interesting. But, still, the image is 32x32 and setting your image from 256 to 256 to 32x32 and it is still pixelized :\ ... I was using Firefox..

Comment: @Canvas But it still looks blurry in 32x32 size... it's original size.

Comment: @DanF has I said in the above comment, you need vendor prefixes. check this updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mt8sk9cb/2/

Comment: @Kaiido I know but I do not want the image 256x256 but rather and its original size of 32x32 and when I set it to 32x32.... it is blurry despite the original image not being blurry.

Answer (score 23):

Your problem is that your css constraints of `canvas{width:512}`vs the canvas property `width=521`will make your browser resample the whole canvas.

To avoid it, remove those css declarations.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var playerImg = new Image()

// http://i.imgur.com/ruZv0dl.png sees a CLEAR, CRISP image
playerImg.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/ruZv0dl.png'
playerImg.width = 32
playerImg.height = 32

playerImg.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(playerImg, 0, 0, 32, 32);
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #ABABAB;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="352" width="521"></canvas>
```

Also, if you were resampling the image (from 32x32 to some other size), @canvas' solution would have been the way to go.

Comment: @DanF you can deal with the accepted mark as you want, but since canvas'one didn't solved your problem, which was caused by the CSS declarations, I think it would have been better for future readers to accept this one and give a bounty to canvas'

Comment: +100, because I came here after I put `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;`, but the image was still blurry.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, had the same problem, my image was not pixel art, and was way bigger, still got the same error, until I change the style="width:x ; height:y" for the  height="x" height="y".

Answer (score 22):

As I encountered this older post for some of my issues, here's even more additional insight to blurry images to layer atop the 'imageSmoothingEnabled' solution.

This is more specifically for the use case of monitor specific rendering and only some people will have encountered this issue if they have been trying to render retina quality graphics into their canvas with disappointing results.

Essentially, high density monitors means your canvas needs to accommodate that extra density of pixels. If you do nothing, your canvas will only render enough pixel information into its context to account for a pixel ratio of 1.

So for many modern monitors who have ratios > 1, you should change your canvas context to account for that extra information but keep your canvas the normal width and height.

To do this you simply set the rendering context width and height to: target width and height * window.devicePixelRatio.

```
canvas.width = target width * window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.height = target height * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Then you set the style of the canvas to size the canvas in normal dimensions:

```
canvas.style.width = `${target width}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${target height}px`;
```

Last you render the image at the maximum context size the image allows. In some cases (such as images rendering svg), you can still get a better image quality by rendering the image at pixelRatio sized dimensions:

```
ctx.drawImage(
    img, 0, 0, 
    img.width * window.devicePixelRatio, 
    img.height * window.devicePixelRatio
  );
```

So to show off this phenomenon I made a fiddle. You will NOT see a difference in canvas quality if you are on a pixelRatio monitor close to 1.

https://jsfiddle.net/ufjm50p9/2/

Comment: And you made mine too ! Got stuck for 2 hours on this problem. And you just solved it ! THANKS!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @canvas answer.

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Works perfect. But in my case changing size of canvas resetting this property back to true.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
}, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```js
img.onload = function () {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
};
img.src = e.target.result;  // your src
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the canvas size to the image or video size before obtaining the context from it.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

const image = document.getElementById("image")
canvas.width = image.width
canvas.height = image.height

// or

const video = document.getElementById("video")
canvas.width = video.videoWidth
canvas.height = video.videoHeight


// finally:

const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

// or

context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

Answer (score -3):

Simple tip: draw with .5 in x and y position. like drawImage(, 0.5, 0.5) :D There you get crisp edges :D

Comment: This is more suitable for a comment than an answer. If you want to post an answer please write detailed explanation.