# HTML5 Canvas bitmaps

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, html5-canvas, vector-graphics

I am building a retro styled game, that uses pixelated images. I have not yet created these images, because I wanted to know the best way of doing things.

These images will probably be a 16 or 32 PX square, but I would like to be able to scale the images as big as I like, just without any blur/distortion.

What format should I use? And how should I import them to my canvas. as well?

**EDIT#1:** Fixed typo & put Q back on topic. (Thank you Spence for pointing it out)

Comment: The HTML 5 Canvas can handle a variety of common image types, I would recommend using `.PNG`. The image software can be your preference: MS Paint (not it doesn't support transparency), Gimp, Photoshop, etc. are all fine. *Note asking for off-site resources is off-topic for this site*, but I hope my comment helped.

Comment: I read that the graphics may end up blurry if they are at a low resolution. In the past colours in the images I've made/edited have mixed/blended. That was back when I barely knew computers tho. (In xp paint)

Comment: I made it on topic again, sorry about that.

Comment: You could try to mix <SVG> with your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create large icon images to which you apply a 16x16 or 32x32 tile effect. Then when you write them to the canvas (after loading the images of course) scale them down to the size you want using

```
context.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height);
```

File sizes are unlikely to jump greatly since each tile should compress fairly easily.

Comment: So the idea is to create a 5Mb file for a 16*16px rendered image? also I don't get the "compress" part, could you extend on it?

Comment: Both JPEG and PNG compress image data - JPEG compression is lossy (the lower the quality, the worse it looks) and PNG is lossless (the more detail in the image the larger the file gets.. The 5MB image file situation occurs if you save it as a BMP file. (Don't)

Comment: hum what? Could you provide a demo to illustrate this? The bigger the image is (in width and height), the bigger the file size will be, whatever compression algo you use. Now, if you do compress it to jpeg, you will create artifacts, even if scaled down, these artifacts will remain.

Comment: File sizes will increase, naturally but not to some huge file size.Using an freeware image viewer, your icon, saved as a PNG at 32 x 32 pixels is 794 bytes. Resized as blocks (not interpolated) and saved at 512  512 pixels, the size if 3382 bytes. (3.3 kb).  Saved as a 512 x 512 BMP file the size is 768 kb. (

Comment: @Kaido Saved to 512 by 512 png outside a browser,  the fiddle image is 2,869 bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89225/discussion-between-traktor53-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 2):

Try "Inkscape", its free

https://inkscape.org/en/

it uses SVG format (scalar vector graphics) so you will be able to scale the images as big as you like, just without any blur/distortion.

Comment: I have tried inkscape in the past, but I didn't think I use it to make a basic bitmap, (where pixelation IS wanted, but not blur)

Answer (score 2):

CanvasContext2d does have an option to disable the image smoothing : [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) which is set to true by default.

According to [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#drawing-images:dom-context-2d-imagesmoothingenabled), if set to false,

> The image [drawn by `drawImage()` method] must be rendered using
>   [nearest-neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation).

This algorithm is the same as the one proposed by @markE in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32492892/3702797).

Unfortunately, browsers still use vendor-prefix for this attribute and it wasn't implemented in both IE9 and IE10...

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img'),
    canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// draw the image
img.onload = function(){
  canvas.width = img.width*50;
  canvas.height = img.height*50;
  // disable smoothing after we change canvas' width/height
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
//32x32px image taken from https://stackoverflow.com/q/31910043/3702797
img.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sp5x.png"
```

```css
canvas{border:.5px solid}
```

```html
<img/>
<canvas></canvas>
```

<sup>*Scroll to see the resized image in canvas*</sup>

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that you should avoid image compression (jpg) if you don't want artifacts. **png** format is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to enlarge without **any** blur or distortion is turn each 1 pixel into a set of 2x2, 3x3, ... pixels.

For example, a single blue pixel in the top-left of the image would become a set of 4 blue pixels at [0,0], [1,0], [0,1] & [1,1]. And the same for every other pixel on the original image. The resulting image would be twice the width & height of the original image.

Since your graphics style is pixelated images, this adjustment would preserve your pixilation while also enlarging the original image.

You can code a function that uses an in-memory html5 canvas to "resize-by-multiplying" your original images as needed. This will use canvas's ability to set the RGBA values every pixel using `context.getImageData` and `context.putImageData`.

Comment: Now, with PNG or jpeg compression, will it be an equivalent/similar size?

Comment: @markE huh? why don't you talk about ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled ? Won't the nearest neighboor algo do exactly what you're proposing?

Comment: The original .png & .jpeg will have set sizes coming in. The resized image (which is really the original image multiplied on an off-screen canvas), will be 2X as large as the original and will contain the same pixelized effect as the original. If your original images are as small as 16x16 or 32x32 you might want to just send an array representing the pixel colors and let the "resize-by-multiply" function use the raw RGBA values to create the new double-sized image.

Comment: @Kaiido. In theory yes, nearest-neighbor would resize-by-multiplication. In past practice, I've experienced browser implementations that fail to follow the nearest-neighbor algorithm precisely. You might post an answer using nearest-neighbor so we can see if the modern browsers do the algorithm justice.

Comment: @markE that may be out of my comprehension. Besides, I may need to change it, and converting it manually may take up a lot of my time. (32^2 is a large amount of px)

Comment: @markE looks good on all modern browsers I've tested (FF, Op, Chrome, Chromium, Safari, IE11) on both mac and win except for IE10&IE9 ! This property wasn't implemented yet...