# How can I avoid to draw a blurred image on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw an image on my canvas but it is blurred, browsing on google I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910043/html5-canvas-drawimage-draws-image-blurry#31910088) but it doesn't work for me. The image is still highly blurred.

> What I've tried:

Created a canvas (width 100%) and loaded a js:

```
<canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
<script src="script_canvas.js"></script>
```

Edited the `script_canvas.js`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var map_image = 'https://i.imgur.com/pnqkqlY.png';
var bin_image = 'https://i.imgur.com/bkwpRrm.png';

make_base();
function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = map_image;
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, base_image.width * 0.28, base_image.height * 0.28);
    }
 }
```

Comment: try to watch this https://jsfiddle.net/62dyvq7o/8/

Comment: Thank you, now is not blurred, but there is no way to make the canvas as width as the html page? (adaptive)

Comment: now I do not have time to try, I think you can set them in javascript or css. I hope this example will help you

https://jsfiddle.net/62dyvq7o/18/