# Drawing image in HTML5 canvas is blurry/squeezed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, drawimage

I am trying to draw an image on the canvas. Problem is, I was trying to draw it as contained within the canvas so that it would look good in different screen resolutions. But the image seems to be squeezed/blurred.

```js
function drawImageScaled(img, ctx) {
  var canvas = ctx.canvas;
  var hRatio = canvas.width / img.width;
  var vRatio = canvas.height / img.height;
  var ratio = Math.min(hRatio, vRatio);
  var centerShift_x = (canvas.width - img.width * ratio) / 2;
  var centerShift_y = (canvas.height - img.height * ratio) / 2;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height,
    centerShift_x, centerShift_y, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
}

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('floor_canvas');
  if (ctx.getContext) {
    ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
    var bg_img = new Image();

    bg_img.onload = function() {
      drawImageScaled(bg_img, ctx);
    };

    bg_img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTm9g.jpg'; //'floor_plan/floor_1.jpg';
  }
}

draw();
```

```css
#floor_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="floor_canvas"></canvas>
```

This is the original image. Viewing it directly shows it in high quality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTm9g.jpg

Any inputs regarding why it appears so?

Comment: The fix seems to be that you need to set the width/height attributes of the canvas in the HTML to match the image size then scale down from there - in this case `width="2662" height="909"`. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: [Don't use CSS width/height on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31910992/6243352).

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. Setting the height and width seems to solve it