How to make images drawn with canvas 2d pixelated
I have a game where im drawing 16x16 images as 256x256 and other high scales. The problem is that they are blurry. I researched how to fix this, but all the articles say that you should make the canvas width 1/4 of the CSS width and set image-rendering to pixelated. This won't work for me since i will be drawing the images at a variety of scales and the higher scales will still be blurry while the lower scales will be downscaled.
I am not sure how i can do this without just upscaling the actual images, which would increase the game size and potentially make compression artifacts.
If any of you know how to do this, it would really help me.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910043/html5-canvas-drawimage-draws-image-blurry

@James that fixed my problem, thanks!
