# How to scale image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to display the image using `cover` simulation in canvas. I've found some cool [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas) on how to do it.

So far my image changes depending on the screen resolution, but only after refreshing the page.

[image]

How can I get the following [scaling effect](http://ohdeergames.com/) without refreshing a page?
Try to resize the window out there.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;

canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);

img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/2010-02-19_3000x2000_chicago_skyline.jpg';

function draw() {
    drawImageProp(ctx, this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

/**
 * By Ken Fyrstenberg
 *
 * drawImageProp(context, image [, x, y, width, height [,offsetX, offsetY]])
 *
 * If image and context are only arguments rectangle will equal canvas
*/
function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        x = y = 0;
        w = ctx.canvas.width;
        h = ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    /// default offset is center
    offsetX = offsetX ? offsetX : 0.5;
    offsetY = offsetY ? offsetY : 0.5;

    /// keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
    if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
    if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
    if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;

    var iw = img.width,
        ih = img.height,
        r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
        nw = iw * r,   /// new prop. width
        nh = ih * r,   /// new prop. height
        cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    /// decide which gap to fill    
    if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;
    if (nh < h) ar = h / nh;
    nw *= ar;
    nh *= ar;

    /// calc source rectangle
    cw = iw / (nw / w);
    ch = ih / (nh / h);

    cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
    cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

    /// make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
    if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
    if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
    if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

    /// fill image in dest. rectangle
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch,  x, y, w, h);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to `draw` on the [window resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize):

```
window.onresize = draw;
```

That should do the trick.

Instead of:

```
drawImageProp(ctx, this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Pass `img` in the `draw` function:

```
drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Then, move the width / heigth settings into the `draw` function, resulting in:

```
function draw() {
    canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
    drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

You may also want to debounce the re-drawing a bit:

```
var timeOut;
window.onresize = function(){
    if(timeOut)
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(draw, 10);
}
```

This prevents the `draw` function from being called a couple of times per second while the window is being resized.

Here's ***[a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGMqWP)***, forked from your codepen.

Comment: Should be noted that scaling on canvas doesn't work. What is drawn on a canvas can't be manipulated like an <img/>.  The image should be redrawn on the resized canvas.

Comment: @Grimbode: I think I've got that covered now.

Comment: Is it best practice to clean the canvas and then redraw or is redrawing good enough if it's previous drawing isn't visible anymore? What does this do with performance?

Comment: Setting the width / height on a canvas already clears the canvas. And setting those attributes is something that has to be done. Redrawing a image on a canvas once is relatively insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

Well this works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdRwVY

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  img = new Image;

canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);

img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/2010-02-19_3000x2000_chicago_skyline.jpg';

function draw() {
  drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
  canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
  draw()
}

/**
 * By Ken Fyrstenberg
 *
 * drawImageProp(context, image [, x, y, width, height [,offsetX, offsetY]])
 *
 * If image and context are only arguments rectangle will equal canvas
 */
function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    x = y = 0;
    w = ctx.canvas.width;
    h = ctx.canvas.height;
  }

  /// default offset is center
  offsetX = offsetX ? offsetX : 0.5;
  offsetY = offsetY ? offsetY : 0.5;

  /// keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
  if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
  if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
  if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
  if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;

  var iw = img.width,
    ih = img.height,
    r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
    nw = iw * r, /// new prop. width
    nh = ih * r, /// new prop. height
    cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

  /// decide which gap to fill    
  if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;
  if (nh < h) ar = h / nh;
  nw *= ar;
  nh *= ar;

  /// calc source rectangle
  cw = iw / (nw / w);
  ch = ih / (nh / h);

  cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
  cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

  /// make sure source rectangle is valid
  if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
  if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
  if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
  if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

  /// fill image in dest. rectangle
  ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch, x, y, w, h);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I think you do need to keep the onload there, because you can resize the window while the image might still not be loaded..

Comment: This will continuously resize (And thus, re-draw) the canvas while you're scaling the window. That's quite inefficient.

Comment: @Cerbrus This option much faster, nonetheless.

Comment: If the speed is a problem, you can lower the delay in my answer from `500` to, say, `10`, or maybe even lower. Then the canvas will re-draw (seemingly) immediately, without actually re-drawing 70 times over the course of the window being resized.