# How to implement SVG's preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" for canvas drawImage method.

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

Is there a workaround for implement SVG's preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" for drawImage() method in canvas?

Comment: you mean when `img` in `drawImage(img, x, y)` refers to an svg doc or just implement the same functionality as this attribute for any image ?

Comment: I want to preserve aspect ratio of images inside canvas using drawImage() method like it's done in svg's preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas) in the marked as duplicate answer indeed does the same operation as `xMinYMin slice` if you call it like `drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0)`.

But for the ones who want the full implementation of the svg's `preserveAspectRatio` attribute, here is one :

It does return an object with `sx,sy,sw,sh,dx,dy,dw,dh` as requested by the `drawImage()` method.

```js
 var preserveAspectRatio = function(source, destination, userString) {

   var srcWidth = source.width,
     srcHeight = source.height,
     destinationW = destination.width,
     destinationH = destination.height;

   // we should keep the whole source
   var aRMeet = function(args) {

     var srcRatio = (srcHeight / srcWidth),
       destRatio = (destinationH / destinationW),

       resultWidth = destRatio > srcRatio ? destinationW : destinationH / srcRatio,
       resultHeight = destRatio > srcRatio ? destinationW * srcRatio : destinationH;

     var getPos = function(arg, res, dest) {

       var max = Math.max(res, dest),
         min = Math.min(res, dest);

       switch (arg) {
         case 'Min': return 0;
         case 'Mid': return (max - min) / 2;
         case 'Max': return max - min;
         default:    return 'invalid';
       }
     };

     var obj = {
       img: returnedImg,
       sx: 0,
       sy: 0,
       swidth: srcWidth,
       sheight: srcHeight,
       dx: getPos(args[0], resultWidth, destinationW),
       dy: getPos(args[1], resultHeight, destinationH),
       dwidth: resultWidth,
       dheight: resultHeight
     };

     if (obj[5] === 'invalid' || obj[6] === 'invalid') {
       return default_obj;
     }

     return obj;
   };

   // we should slice the larger part
   var aRSlice = function(args) {

     var resultWidth, resultHeight;

     var a = function() {
       resultWidth = destinationW;
       resultHeight = srcHeight * destinationW / srcWidth;
     };

     var b = function() {
       resultWidth = srcWidth * destinationH / srcHeight;
       resultHeight = destinationH;
     };

     if (destinationW > destinationH) {
       a();
       if (destinationH > resultHeight) {
         b();
       }
     } else if (destinationW === destinationH) {
       if (srcWidth > srcHeight) {
         b();
       } else {
         a();
       }
     } else {
       b();
       if (destinationW > resultWidth) {
         a();
       }
     }

     var getPos = function(arg, res, dest, src) {
       switch (arg) {
         case 'Min': return 0;
         case 'Mid': return (res - dest) / 2 * src / res;
         case 'Max': return (res - dest) * src / res;
         default: return 'invalid';
       }
     };

     var x = getPos(args[0], resultWidth, destinationW, srcWidth);
     var y = getPos(args[1], resultHeight, destinationH, srcHeight);

     var obj = {
       img: returnedImg,
       sx: x,
       sy: y,
       swidth: srcWidth - x,
       sheight: srcHeight - y,
       dx: 0,
       dy: 0,
       dwidth: resultWidth - (x * (resultWidth / srcWidth)),
       dheight: resultHeight - (y * (resultHeight / srcHeight)),
     };

     if (obj[1] === 'invalid' || obj[2] === 'invalid') {
       return default_obj;
     }

     return obj;
   };

   // check if the object passed was drawable over a canvas
   var returnedImg = source.nodeName === 'IMG' || source.nodeName === 'VIDEO' || source.nodeName === 'CANVAS' ? source : null;

   // if an invalid string or none is set as the preserveAspectRatio, this should be considered as "xMidYMid meet"
   var default_obj = aRMeet(['Mid', 'Mid']);

   if (!userString) {
     return default_obj;
   } else {

     var args = userString.trim().split(' '),
       minMidMax = args[0].replace('x', '').split('Y');

     switch (args[args.length - 1]) {
       case "meet":  return aRMeet(minMidMax);
       case "slice": return aRSlice(minMidMax);
       default:      return default_obj;
     }
   }
 };

  //
  //  Snippet code 
  //_______________

 var images = [new Image(), new Image(), new Image()];
 var img = images[0];
 var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

 var ctxL = outputLandscape.getContext('2d');
 var ctxP = outputPortrait.getContext('2d');
 var ctxS = outputSquare.getContext('2d');

 var update = function() {
   ctxL.clearRect(0, 0, outputLandscape.width, outputLandscape.height);
   ctxP.clearRect(0, 0, outputPortrait.width, outputPortrait.height);
   ctxS.clearRect(0, 0, outputSquare.width, outputSquare.height);

   var aspectRatioStr = 'x' + selects[0].value + 'Y' + selects[1].value + ' ' + selects[2].value;

   var p = preserveAspectRatio(img, outputPortrait, aspectRatioStr);
   ctxP.drawImage(p.img, p.sx, p.sy, p.swidth, p.sheight, p.dx, p.dy, p.dwidth, p.dheight);

   var l = preserveAspectRatio(img, outputLandscape, aspectRatioStr);
   ctxL.drawImage(l.img, l.sx, l.sy, l.swidth, l.sheight, l.dx, l.dy, l.dwidth, l.dheight);

   var s = preserveAspectRatio(img, outputSquare, aspectRatioStr);
   ctxS.drawImage(s.img, s.sx, s.sy, s.swidth, s.sheight, s.dx, s.dy, s.dwidth, s.dheight);

   svgImagePortrait.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', aspectRatioStr);
   svgImageLandscape.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', aspectRatioStr);
   svgImageSquare.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', aspectRatioStr);
 };

 for (var i = 0; i < selects.length - 1; i++) {
   selects[i].onchange = update;
 }
 selects[3].onchange = function() {
   img = images[+this.value];
   update();
   svgImagePortrait.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', img.src);
   svgImageLandscape.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', img.src);
   svgImageSquare.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', img.src);

 }

 img.onload = function() {
   svgImagePortrait.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', this.src);
   svgImageLandscape.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', this.src);
   svgImageSquare.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', this.src);

   update();
 };


 images[0].src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/200";
 images[1].src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/100";
 images[2].src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200";
```

```css
html,body,canvas {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: .9em;
}
svg,canvas {
  display: inline-block;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
x
<select name="x">
  <option value="Min">Min</option>
  <option value="Mid">Mid</option>
  <option value="Max">Max</option>
</select>
Y
<select name="Y">
  <option value="Min">Min</option>
  <option value="Mid">Mid</option>
  <option value="Max">Max</option>
</select>

<select name="slice_meet">
  <option value="slice">slice</option>
  <option value="meet">meet</option>
</select>
image format :
<select name="format">
  <option value="0">portrait</option>
  <option value="1">landscape</option>
  <option value="2">square</option>
</select>
<br>

<canvas id="outputLandscape" width="280" height="200"></canvas>
<svg width="280" height="200" viewBox="0 0 280 200">
  <image id="svgImageLandscape" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
</svg>
<br>
<canvas id="outputPortrait" width="200" height="280"></canvas>
<svg width="200" height="280" viewBox="0 0 200 280">
  <image id="svgImagePortrait" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
</svg>
<br>
<canvas id="outputSquare" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <image id="svgImageSquare" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: I will also try this.Thank you for the answer.