# Rendering video element to canvas - unwanted stretching?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to generate a screenshot of a video. The goal is to generate an image that is identical to the first frame of the video. However, I'm facing an issue with the resulting image being stretched.

This image displays the video on the left, paused at the very beginning - and the generated image on the right:

[image]

Notice the grey area at the bottom? It has been stretched to a taller height than that of the video.

I am using the following code the generate the screenshot:

Example Markup:

```
<video id="video" height="300" width="320" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://domain.com/video.mp4">
</video>
<canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="320"></canvas>
```

Script:

```
// Grab an existing video element, 300px tall, 320px wide.
var video = document.getElementById('video');
// Grab existing canvas, 300px tall, 320px wide.
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
// Wait until video has loaded
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Render using same dimensions.
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 300);
}, false);
```

Could someone please advise me on how to avoid this stretching?

Comment: The `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height` attributes are only the page display properties and are not related to the canvas pixel resolution. You need to set the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to the correct resolution

Comment: I am setting the width and height directly on the element. I've added the markup I used to create my example screenshot into the question example code.

Comment: No you have to set it to the media's width and height, video element's size attributes are only displaying sizes too. You can retrieve it by js with `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like for `<img>` elements, `<video>` element's `width` and `height` attributes resize the container. `drawImage`method in other hand do use the content.

You then have to use the `videoElement.videoWidth` and `videoElement.videoHeight` attributes to retrieve the media's width and height (*or `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight` for image elements*).

So you've got two possibilities :

Either you want to make a capture of the video, in its real size :

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
btn.onclick = function(){
  // set your canvas width and height to the media's ones
  canvas.width = vid.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = vid.videoHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(vid, 0,0);
  };
```

```html
<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="200" height="100" autoplay controls muted loop id="vid"></video><button id="btn">take a screenshot</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Or if you want to take a screenshot of your video element, you'll face more
complexity since you'll have to fake the default `object-fit: contain;` CSS property. This can be done thanks to the `ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);` properties.

You can find one way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas), and a more complete one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428723/how-to-implement-svgs-preserveaspectratio-xminymin-slice-for-canvas-drawimage) so I won't include it in this answer, just remember to use the `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight` attributes as sourceWidth and sourceHeight.

Comment: Are you thinking that the natural size of the video is not the same as what I'm setting it to? I'm not resizing the video - the frame width is 320px and frame height is 300px on the mp4 file. As in your example, I'm simply trying to take a screenshot of the video with it's natural size. Yet the resulting screenshot seems to have its contents stretched.

Comment: @Tyler Well yes, that's what I'm thinking given your explanations. It's the only possibility I can think of. Can you check that `video.videoHeight === 300` on your side?

Comment: Yes, `video.videoHeight` is showing as 300. I made a fiddle with a basic version of what I'm trying to do so you can see the actual video I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/owLgg94b/

Comment: Ok, I'm able to [reproduce it](http://jsfiddle.net/owLgg94b/2/) but only on chrome... and [only with **your** video](http://jsfiddle.net/owLgg94b/3/). you may raise a bug to there bugzilla..., and I'll try to find some more time to investigate it. But right now, I'll let this general answer since you seem to be in a very particular case.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I just tested the fiddle again this morning and the bug is showing up on my PC but not my Mac - using the exact same version of Chrome.

Comment: @Tyler, no I'm on a mac. Didn't had time yet to analyse your video file (seems legit at first glance). Are you saying that the bug occurs also with the other example video on your windows?

Comment: The other example video seems fine - but I am only able to reproduce the stretching on my Windows Desktop + Chrome. Chrome on Mac is displaying correctly.