# Setting image size percentage in canvas and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to create a one-pager at the moment with a canvas where you can click to add/place images at random. I've gotten most of what I want to work, but being extremely new to jquery and canvas, I still can't figure out how to set a max-size for my images. As far as I've understood, it can be quite hard to make images on a canvas work perfectly when you haven't set the canvas size manually in css, but I have a resizing canvas, so I'm not really sure how I get around that.

I want the images that I place to have a max-height/max-width of 80% of the viewport. I tried setting a max size in css, but it didn't do anything.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5cL6ant/20/)

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
   var images = [];
    $("#siteload").fadeIn(1500);
   $('.put').each(function() {
     images.push($(this).attr('src'));
    });
    (function() {
    var
        htmlCanvas = document.getElementById('c'),
        context = htmlCanvas.getContext('2d');
        initialize();
        img = new Image();
        count = 0;
        htmlCanvas.onclick= function(evt) {
        img.src = images[count];
          var x = evt.offsetX - img.width/2,
              y = evt.offsetY - img.height/2;
          context.drawImage(img, x, y);
          count++;
          if (count == images.length) {
          count = 0;
          }
        }
      function initialize() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        resizeCanvas();
      }
      function resizeCanvas() {
        htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      }
    })();
  });
  $(".hvr_cnt").mouseenter(function () {
      title = $("<div class='hvr_ttl'>" + $(this).children()[0].title + "</div>");
      $(this).children()[0].title = "";
      $(this).append(title);
  });
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     $('.hvr_ttl').css({
       top: e.pageY - $(".hvr_ttl").height()/2,
       left:  e.pageX - $(".hvr_ttl").width()/2
     });
   });
  $(".hvr_cnt").mouseleave(function (e) {
     $(this).children()[0].title = $($(this).children()[1]).html();
     $(this).children()[1].remove();
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.slides {
  display: none
}

#c {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.hvr_ttl {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: none;
}

.hvr_cnt {
  cursor: none;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}
```

```html
<body ontouchstart="">
  <div class="hvr_cnt">
    <canvas id="c" title="click"></canvas>
  </div>
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" class="put" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/google/56/thumbs-up-sign_1f44d.png" class="put" /></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: do you want to set image height and width as 80% of height and width of canvas?

Comment: yes. I'll be adding a few different images to the list, with different proportions, so I need them to be max-width/max-height to keep the proportions

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
htmlCanvas.onclick= function(evt) {
        img.src = images[count];

        img.width = 80/100*  htmlCanvas.width;
        img.height = 80/100*  htmlCanvas.height;

          var x = evt.offsetX - img.width/2,
              y = evt.offsetY - img.height/2;
          // context.drawImage(img, x, y);
     context.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width, img.height);
          count++;
          if (count == images.length) {
          count = 0;
          }


        }
```

Comment: That's almost right, but is there a way to keep the original proportions of the images? In other words, setting up a maximum height/width, instead of a forced height/width?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width,img.height,0,0,htmlCanvas.width,htmlCanvas.height);
```

you also can use `background-size:cover;`

Comment: I still need the image to be placed at the x y coordinates, as well as keep the original proportions of the images, so this doesn't work I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

The max-height/width doesn't work because everything within the canvas is independent from your css.

If you want to set the image to 80% use `htmlCanvas.width` and `htmlCanvas.height` to calculate the new size and use `context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h)` to set the image size when drawing.

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas/21961894#21961894) could be helpful.

Comment: hmm, I see. But would I be able to set the image to have a percentage-based height of canvas, yet retain a proportional width? Might be a stupid question but I'm afraid code is still extremely unfamiliar territory...

Comment: As you set the x and y coordinates you have to do some math to calculate the new size of your image. The canvas provides no out of the box function which do the math for you.