# How to put text on a background image which is on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I wanted to know how do I put text on top of the image which is in the canvas. The image needs to be in the canvas since it is part of my game (Breakout). I get some text but it goes behind the image which is annoying.

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Breakout</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#4d0000">

    <p align="center">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="800" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    </p>

    <script>

    window.onload = function(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function(){
         context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
         context.font = "40pt Calibri";
         context.fillText("BREAKOUT", 625, 100);
     };
     imageObj.src = 'C:/Users/study/Desktop/Breakout/Images/test3.jpg'; 
};  



    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Draw the image first, and the text second.

Comment: @FrankerZ No difference

Comment: What @FrankerZ said is the best answer. Another solution could be to set the `globalCompositeOperation` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation to `destination-over` before drawing the image.

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner Show your code. Did you perhaps put it after the `.onload()` and not within that function?

Comment: @FrankerZ How do you put it in the function?

Comment: @lemieuxster That does not work either

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner - it seemed to have worked for me? https://jsfiddle.net/uxe0ta3o/1/ Like FrankerZ said, it would be helpful to see your updated code.

Comment: @lemieuxster So that's how you do it, I did find another solution but I might use this. How do I put my updated code on here? Does it matter if that image is a background image or a normal image since I will be putting other features such as buttons on it?

Comment: I believe you can edit the post. If not, then providing a link in the comments would work.

Comment: @lemieuxster I edited the code so this is the solution I found. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what @FrankerZ meant when he said to change the order before.  Good job!

Comment: @lemieuxster uhh yh thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code you tried, it is not visible in the canvas because of the position of the text `context.fillText("BREAKOUT", 625, 100);`

So, just change the position of the text or increase the image size

This helps you [Simulation background-size: cover in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas)

Now you can have your text wherever possible!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Breakout</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#4d0000">

    <p align="center">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="800" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    </p>

    <script>

      window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
          context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
          context.font = "40pt Calibri";
          context.fillText("BREAKOUT", 20, 80, imageObj.width*2, imageObj.height * 2);

        };

        imageObj.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350'; 

      };  



    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Debug yourself whether the text is displaying before the image is loaded?
So, if you have tried something like this

```
window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = "40pt Calibri";
        context.fillText("BREAKOUT", 620, 100);
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
          context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        };
        imageObj.src = 'C:/Users/study/Desktop/Breakout/Images/test3.jpg'; 
      };
```

The text won't be displayed! so just change the text position to something like `context.fillText("BREAKOUT", 20, 80);` and see, the text appears. So There is no problem with the code you have written.

Hope you got the answer to the question.

Thank you.