# Make canvas stretch to fit image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, html5-canvas

I have a canvas in which I want to render various images, depending on the user. Right now the canvas is fixed size like this:

```
<canvas width="400" height="300" id={'canvas'}/>
```

This is how I'm rendering the image:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(nextProps.image)
}
```

But this is what's happening:

[image]

So the image at the bottom is too big to be in the canvas, and the other image is too small to fill the image. Also if the image is anything other then a 400x300, it gets cut. How can I prevent it?

Comment: This might help you, Please have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas/21961894#21961894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get dynamically your canvas dimensions you could have the following `componentWillReceiveProps()` method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(nextProps.image)
}
```

Comment: There was a little more logic to it, but this was the main point. Forgot to add the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try by providing the canvas width and height along with ctx.drawImage like:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 300);
```

Comment: Ok this is kind of it. I just need to make it fluid now. Thanks! (Will select as best in 4 minutes)