# How to crop images when placing them on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas

I want to add images to an HTML5 canvas in a grid pattern. The canvas is square but the images are of various sizes and aspect ratios. I want to crop all the images into squares.

I have the algorithm to place the images onto the canvas as squares but the images are stretched / squeezed.

[image: grid]

How to crop the landscape and or portrait images into squares.

Here is the algorithm:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
for (let xCell = 0; xCell < 5; xCell++) {
  for (let yCell = 0; yCell < 5; yCell++) {
    const x = xCell * 200;
    const y = yCell * 200;
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      // how to crop into squares?
      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 200, 200);
    };
    img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';
  }
}
```

How to crop the images:
[image: crop1]
[image: crop2]

Comment: What you're looking for is to emulate CSS's **object-fit: cover** - See i.e: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21961839/383904 - to be done in a separate off-screen canvas. Then after the transformation, and after you get the imageData of that offscreen canvas — you're mostly done with the hardest part, and then all it takes is to draw that data to the on-screen canvas — as tiles.

Comment: Your nested for loops execute `img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';` **25** times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested for loops execute `img.onload` and `img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';` 25 times.

```js
let ii = 0;
for (let xCell = 0; xCell < 5; xCell++) {
  for (let yCell = 0; yCell < 5; yCell++) {
    console.log(++ii + ": ", xCell, yCell);
  }
}
```

---

Here's one way to use four predetermined x,y coordinate groups:

```js
[[0,0],[200,0],[0,200],[200,200]].forEach(function ([x,y]) {
    console.log(x,y);
});
```

To crop and place an image in an [HTML Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) you need to  use all available [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) parameters. First crop (and resize if necessary) the image you're loading, then place it on the `canvas`.

```
drawImage(image, 

    // source image crop and resize
    // sx, sy = upper left coordinates of crop location
    // sWidth, sHeight = dimensions of crop
    sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, 

    // placement of image on canvas
    // dx, dy = upper left coordinates of placement
    // dWidth, dHeight = dimensions of placement on canvas
    dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight

)
```

For example:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

// loop array of 4 [x,y] desired coordinates
[[0,0],[200,0],[0,200],[200,200]].forEach(function ([x,y]) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652957251843-dcc1a7cfc4be?w=1080';

  img.onload = function() {
    const [imgw, imgh] = [this.width, this.height];
    ctx.drawImage(img, 
    
        // crop (250, 350) and resize ((imgw / 2.5), (imgh / 2.5)) source image
        250, 350, (imgw / 2.5), (imgh / 2.5), 
      
        // place image on canvas
        x, y, 200, 200 
    );
  };
});
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

`drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`
[image: example]